# ¿ Cómo predecir mediante un regresor usando una o varias columnas?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, predicción

He realizado una predicción para calcular porcentaje de carga en la batería de mi móvil, a partir de 2 columnas, "tiempo de carga" y  "nivel" a partir de un _CSV que contenia dichas variables.

Código:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

datos = pd.read_csv("bateria.csv")
x = datos["Tiempo"]
y = datos["Carga"]
X = x[:,np.newaxis]
i=0

while True:

    i+=1;
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y)

    mlr = MLPRegressor(solver='lbfgs',alpha = 1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(3,3),random_state=1)
    mlr.fit(X_train,y_train) # Entrenamos
    print(mlr.score(X_train,y_train))
    if mlr.score(X_train,y_train) > 0.98:
        break
    
    print("Prediccion en T=20 minutos ", mlr.predict(20))
    print("Iteraciones: ",i)
```

*El resultado es muy positivo porque en el archivo CSV tengo `20` y la predicción me calcula `20.27`.*

Ahora, **quisiera poner 3 columnas para predecir**, por ejemplo, si como fruta ( una variable dummy inventada ), pero no logro hacerlo porque con *SciKitLearn* solo he trabajado con 2 columnas. ¿Cómo puedo usar mas de una variable para predecir mi Target?

```
"Día"     "Mes"     "Fruta"
lunes     enero       no
martes    marzo       no
domingo   enero       si
```

Por otor lado: ¿Es posible ponerle pasar mis variable la predictor sin usar los valores del set de test ?

Comment: Al ejecutar tu código, todo lo demás corre bien, pero esta linea no he podido, ya que me da este error print("Prediccion en T=20 minutos ", mlr.predict(20)) ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=20.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar las variables que quieras,

> x representa en este código el conjunto de variables con las que
> deseas predecir.

Podrías disponer de las siguientes que mencionas en un dataframe, por ejemplo:

```
random_size = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({"Tiempo": np.random.normal(size=random_size), 
      "Carga": np.random.normal(size=random_size),
      "Mes": np.random.uniform(low=1, high=12, size=random_size),
      "Dia": np.random.uniform(low=1, high=7, size=random_size)})
```

Luego elegir las que te interesen (usaré todas de ejemplo en una lista pero podrías elegir mas o menos cantidad) por ejemplo:

```
x = df[["Tiempo", "Mes", "Dia"]]
```

Por último si deseas una predicción puntual puedes pasar un dataframe con los valores que deseas y predecir, por ejemplo usando un valor del dataframe original:

```
mlr.predict(x[["Tiempo", "Mes", "Dia"]][:1])
```